# How to disable AspectJ compilation via configuration

Tags: java, aop, aspect

I implement my aspect class in Java style:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {
  @Pointcut("...")
  public void somePointcut() {}

  @Around("somePointcut()")
  public ...
}
```

I am new to AspectJ. I want to know if there a convenient/centralized way to control the effectiveness of the `Pointcut` so I can enable/disable them based on some configuration **at compile time**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During **runtime** you can just use an [`if()` pointcut](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697), but I know this is not what you want.

For **compile time** it depends on how you build your project. I am going to assume you use Maven and the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).

Let us further assume that you configure the plugin to run in the `process-sources` phase like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>-->
        <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
        <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
        <!--<warn>constructorName,packageDefaultMethod,deprecation,maskedCatchBlocks,unusedLocals,unusedArguments,unusedImport</warn>-->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Then just add a Maven profile - let us call it `skip-aspectj` which overwrites the phase to none via `<phase/>`:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skip-aspectj</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase/>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now if you run your Maven build

- normally, the aspects are compiled and applied,
- with `mvn -P skip-aspectj ...` they will be inactive and the whole AspectJ Maven execution just skipped.